# Sometimes getting quotes in Oracle spool sometimes not

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

Using Oracle SQL Developer, I do:

```
spool c:\temp\file1.csv
select /*csv*/ id, version, key, pattern, name from mydatabase.edition;

spool c:\temp\file2.csv
select /* csv */ id, version, amount, item FROM mydatabase.mtci;
```

In the first statment the export is like this

```
"string1", 98, "key1", "pattern", "name"
```

In the next statement it is like thhis

```
string2,       104,         988.99,         yuikk
```

i.e. it has no quotes and has tabs after the commas.

Anyone know why this is the case?

Note: I am using Oracle 11.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in on case I was doing

```
/*csv*/ -- this works

/* csv */ -- this does not work.
```

Thanks